# Using a 4-pin computer fan controller without the load

Tags: sensor, transistors, cpu, hall-effect, fan

Is it OK if I use the controller from a CPU fan without connecting the motor's coils?

All I want is to use the Hall effect sensor.

The datasheet is posted [here](http://goo.gl/6atkj), the driving output circuit uses a darlington pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see from datasheet how to use hall sensor separately, but noone should die or explode if you would not connect the load (in the worst case you may connect some resistor as a tiny load).